# Is there any way to run an application direct to the device on Corona SDK?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, gideros

It is very time-consuming to build an application, copy the apk on the device, install it and run it, just because you want to change the value of a variable. Is there any way to run an application straight to the phone (like in Unity) ?

Does Gideros or any other similar SDK offer this capability? I read that ZeroBrane offers on device debugging but I didn't find any more tutorial/information how can you do it.

Answer (score 2):

Gideros provides exactly such capability, you just install Gideros Player on your device, enter IP address on your computer, and instantly run your app on device, without any exporting or building, just click play.

Additionally with combination of ZeroBrane you can achieve live coding 
http://bowerhaus.eu/blog/files/live_coding.html

Answer (score 1):

Corona cannot do that without ZeroBrane LiveCoding.

Gideros do that by default.

Answer (score 0):

There are [tutorials](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/debugging-and-live-coding-with-corona-sdk-applications-and-zerobrane-studio) and documentation at the ZeroBrane site for doing remote device debugging (and even live coding for some frameworks).

Generally remote debug requires that the on-device code be able to load the modules `mobdebug` (provided with ZBS) and `luasocket`.